# AspectJ pointcut in object-aspect is not working

Tags: java, aspectj

I just can't find out why my pointcut is not working. Compiler does not give any warnings, so I cannot explain why it is not working. I'm using aspectjrt 1.7.2 and aspectjtools 1.7.0 in a maven javafx application.

My aspect looks like this

```
public privileged aspect MovieAspect perthis(MovieInit()) {

pointcut MovieInit(): execution(Movie.new(..));

pointcut reloadMainPanelView(): cflow(execution(void main.views.MainFrame.MainPanel.fillMainPanel(..)));

before(ArrayList tar): target(tar) && reloadMainPanelView() && call(void java.util.ArrayList.clear())
                       && !within(MovieAspect) {
    System.out.println("test");
}
```

my MovieAspect is located in package main.models

And here a little explanation of what is actually happening within my code

---

when my gui loads I initialize the MainFrame class. Just before that another aspect loads all movie-objects. And then when the MainFrame initializes the views for the movie-objects in the MainPanel it first clears its view-objects and reloads them. Because I added all those views as listener to the corresponding movie-object I need to remove them again. Of course I could do just before calling the clear-method of the ArrayList but I really would like to know why the pointcut is not working.
The MovieAspect-objects do get instantiated, I tested this with the MovieInit() pointcut.

---

does anyone have a clue, why this pointcut does not work? actually all pointcuts on outer classes in the same package or not do not work except for those in class Movie.

hope someone can help.

EDIT:

this is a catch to all constructors of the movie-class but it doesn't matter. After hours of research I found the solution. This text explains this behaviour

> 4.3.4 Implicit limiting of join points

Using the per-object or per-control-flow association has the side effect of implicitly
limiting the advice in the aspect to only join points that match the scope of
an aspect instance. The scope of an aspect instance is the set of join points that
have an aspect instance associated with them. For example, for the percflow()
association, the scope of an aspect instance is all the join points occurring inside
the control flow of the specified pointcut. This means that even if a pointcut specified for an advice matches a join point, the advice to that join point won’t
apply unless the join point also matches the scope of the aspect. This side effect
often surprises developers when they refactor an aspect to create reusable parts
and need to use per- associations.
The aspect association implies that advice in an aspect will apply to join
points only if:

■ For perthis() associations, the join point’s execution object matches the
aspect instance’s associated object.

■ For pertarget() associations, the join point’s target object matches the
aspect’s associated object.

■ For percflow() associations, the join point is in the control flow of the
aspect’s associated control flow.

■ For percflowbelow() associations, the join point is below the control flow
of the aspect’s associated control flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure MovieInit() pointcut catches the call to movie constructor? 
Is this Movie constructor method a default constructor or a user-defined one?